# Django Rest Framework how to serialize a many to many relational Model?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, many-to-many, django-orm, django-serializer

I am doing a project in Django Rest Framework. Now I am trying to serialize many to many relations, but I don't know how this works. Here is my models' code:

Model  for files

```
def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
    return 'user_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.user.id, filename)


class Document(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    document = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Model for Expenses and loans

```
class Expenses(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    amount = models.DecimalField(default=0.0, decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    additional_files = models.ManyToManyField(Document, blank=True, related_name="expenses")  # Upload multiple files

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Loans(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    amount = models.DecimalField(default=0.0, decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
    loan_from = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    additional_files = models.ManyToManyField(Document, blank=True, related_name="loans")  # Upload multiple files

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**My question**:
Just want to know how to serialize these `additional_files` in the Expenses and Loans.

- It will be much better if give resources and explanations of how that works.

Answer (score 1):

For `List` endpoint you could make something like that:

**serializers.py**

```py
class ListDocumentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):   
    # Document fields


class ListLoansSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()
    additional_files = ListDocumentSerializer(many=True)
    # other loans model fields
```

**views.py**

```py
class ListLoansApi(APIView):

    permission_classes = []    
   
    def get(self, request):

        loans = Loans.objects.prefetch_related('additional_files') # prefetch_related for ORM optimization with M2M 

        loans_data = ListDoctorSerializer(loans, many=True).data

        return Response(loans_data)
```

Comment: What will do for model Serializer?

Comment: I didn't try it before, and `serializers.ModelSerializer` is not recommended for performance issues!